# How to implement GORM Value interface

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to implement the Value interfaces for a db model, however I only receive an empty object when the Value function is called. The models are stored in the table as Link's but when I read them I want to append an additional field by using the value interface, the function is called however I'm not sure how I can access the original entry so that I can append the name to it

I define my struct as such:

```
type Link struct {
    Id string
    Url string
}

type ReturnLink struct {
    Link
    Name string
}

func (l *Link) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    fmt.Println("scan")
    return nil
}

func (l Link) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    fmt.Println("value")
    name := getName()
    returnLink := ReturnLink{
        Link: l,
        Name: name,
    }
    return returnLink, nil
}
```

Once I have formed the query, I am able to scan the value into the struct:

```
var link ReturnLink
db.Model(&Link{}).Where("id = ?", id).Scan(&link)
```

This returns a correct link with an empty name when I don't define the Value interface, but once implemented it only returns null values for each field, is there something I'm missing?

I have also tried not implementing the scan interface but it changes nothing

Comment: The Valuer interface is used when a value that's going to go into the db is needed,  so would only be relevant when you are calling Save, Update, etc. 
Can you list what the link table schema is. You used the `Query` function of `*gorm.DB`, but no such function exists, so maybe a you need to write a fuller code sample that actually compiles.

Comment: I have updated the query. The link table schema uses the Link struct. If the Value interface is used when updating records, how come it is called when I use Scan in the query? Is there a reason why the Scan interface wouldn't be called at all, because its not at the moment